# show/hide multiple options in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show/hide more than 100 options in single select dropdown list. My code so far is like below. However, it seems good for small number of options but not for large number of options. Is there a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#colors").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        url = "http://domain.com";
        if(selectedValue == "color1"){
          $("table#color1").show();
          $("table#color2").hide();
          $("table#color3").hide();
          $.get(url, {name: "color1"});
        }   
        if(selectedValue == "color2"){
          $("table#color1").hide();
          $("table#color2").show();
          $("table#color3").hide();
          $.get(url, {name: "color2"});
        }
        if(selectedValue == "color3"){
          $("table#color1").hide();
          $("table#color2").hide();
          $("table#color3").show();
          $.get(url, {name: "color3"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use classes : 1/ hide all 2/ show only the required ; is this just examples or you really can map the name to the selectedValue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give all tables a class (e.g. `class="colored-table"`) and do following:

```
$('table.colored-table').hide();
$('table#' + selectedValue).show();
// 'table#' + selectedValue : will become 'table#color1' if selectedValue equals 'color1' and so on
$.get(url, {name: selectedValue});
```

(edit: forgot the $.get)

Answer (score 1):

If they all have a class called e.g. `color`, you'd be able to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#colors").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        url = "http://domain.com";
        $("table.color").hide();
        $("table#"+selectedValue).show();
        $.get(url, {name: selectedValue});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery "not" selector, (if a table does not have an id attribute of "color3"):

```
if(selectedValue == "color3"){
    $("table").not('#color3').hide();
    $("table#color3").show();
    $.get(url, {name: "color3"});
}
```

Or you could just hide all of the tables and then just show the one you need:

```
if(selectedValue == "color3"){
    $("table").hide();
    $("table#color3").show();
    $.get(url, {name: "color3"});
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first table must be open when the page is loaded. It's solved already, thanks.